# How to add z-index for inner div

Tags: css, z-index

I'm creating a form, in which adding icon whcih stated about the field when user hover on the icon.

Below is my code and css :

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #83837F;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltiptext:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 100001;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 8px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #83837F;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="tooltip" style="float:right;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/1/">
    <span class="tooltiptext">
      Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="tooltip" style="float:right;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/3/">
    <span class="tooltiptext">
      Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For above when I hover first `tooltip` then its `tooltiptext` visible but the second `tooltip` img is overlapping it.

I want to add highest z-index to `tooltiptext` so that the tooltip img which is coming below it, don't overlap it.

Comment: Can you draw and attach a picture of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Now you can add to two property in your `.tooltip .tooltiptext` like this `left:10px; right:10px;` and remove to `width: 350px;`

Below is an example of this code:

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
 
  background-color: #83837F;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
left:10px;right:10px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltiptext:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 100001;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 8px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #83837F;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="tooltip" style="float:right;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/1/">
    <span class="tooltiptext">
      Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="tooltip" style="float:right;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/3/">
    <span class="tooltiptext">
      Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text Custom Text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```